# Android camera byte[] array to 2D array

Tags: android, arrays, android-camera

I'm a little confused about the byte[] array output from the Android camera. A picture is essentially a 2D array, so why is the output only 1D?

I'm trying to take the byte array output and perform a Fourier transform on it, and for that to happen I need the data to be in a 2D double array. So how do I get from the camera output byte array to a 2D double array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1D array is flattened 2D array. To convert it to 2D array, you need something like this:

```
double[][] array2D = new double[width][height];

for(int i = 0 ; i < array2D.length ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < array2D[i].length ; i++)
    {
        array2D[i][j] = array1D[i * array2D.length + j];
    }
}
```

Width and height might be other way round.

Comment: I've been using Toast to print out the size of the byte array...the size changes every time. Sometimes its 413128, other times its 611611, or other numbers in between, so I don't get how this answer can possibly work.